# Allocate values by month and by spend category

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following first table as data. Is there any way to get result as in second table.

[image: Screenshot]

Please note that Start Month and End Month are shown as mm-yyyy.

To clarify the calculations:

- The second table has a column for each month that is contained in any of the event intervals.
- Each event expense is evenly divided across the months for that event.
- Although the example shows no expense category being used for more than one event, that can happen.  In that case, expenses for a given cost category would be aggregated each month.

  So, for example, say both events had an advertising expense, and Event A's was $600.  Event A's monthly allocation would be $200 because it is a three-month event.  So The April advertising amount in table 2 would be $200 for Event A and $500 for Event B, or $700.

Comment: You show two events and none of the expense categories overlap.  Can we assume that they could possibly overlap?  So, for example, if both events had am advertising expense, those allocations would be consolidated by month on the advertising line in the second table?

Comment: Hi, yes they could overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly speaking, the first table may be suitable for human to read but is not suitable for computer to calculate or do some statistics. To get table 2, the ideal is simple - to get the divided one **for each month for each event for each category expense** (and store them into some helper cells), then to sum them up accordingly. To get the divided expense, we need to first get a flag if that given month falls into the range of time.

I assume you need twelve months. I also assume the cell for start month has date of first day of that month (e.g. 2017-04-01 for `B2`, 04/2017), and accordingly, the cell for end month has date of last day of that month (e.g. 2017-06-30 for `C2`, 06/2017).

1. **Flag**: Uses `H1` to `S1` as date for each month, i.e. 01/2017 (2017-01-01), 02/2017 (2017-02-01), ..., 12/2017 (2017-12-01), and uses left cells of column `H` to `S` as flag of if that month is in range. In `H2`, uses formula `=AND($B2<=H$1,H$1<=$C2)`. **Caveat: Please note the different usage of `$` in the formula to have the absolute reference to cells to allow copying easily.** It means if current month (in top row of current column) is in between start and end month, returns true, otherwise returns false. Then copy this formula to right till column `S` and copy down to last of the events.
2. **Count**: Uses column `T` as counter of months among which expense to be divided. Formula in `T2` is `=COUNTIF(H2:S2,TRUE)`, then copy formula down.
3. **Divided Expense for each category:** Again, please note the usage of `$` in following formula.

   3.1  **1st category**: Uses column `U` to `AF` (1st group of 12 columns) as divided expense for 1st category, i.e. "Advertisement"; Formula of `U2` is `=IF(H2,$E2/$T2,0)`, means if flag of that month is true (i.e. that month is in range), returns divided expense (adv. expense/months count), otherwise zero. Then copy right (till column `AF`), copy down.

   3.2  **2nd category**: Uses column `AG` to `AR` (2nd group of 12 columns) as divided expense for 2nd category, i.e. "Fairs&Seminars"; Formula of `AG2` is `=IF(H2,$F2/$T2,0)`. Then copy right (till `AR`) and copy down.

   3.3  **3rd category**: Uses column `AS` to `BD` (3rd group of 12 columns) as divided expense for 3rd category, i.e. "Accommodation"; Formula of `AS2` is `=IF(H2,$G2/$T2,0)`. Then copy right (till `BD`) and copy down.
4. **Sum them up**: In table two, for each month, sum corresponding expense up for all events.